# How to trigger keyboard enter event to add indentation on next line of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html text-area when user put colon(:) and press enter there should be indentation on next line of **text-area**

My code

```html
<textarea id="yourcode" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

What i have tried

```js
$('#yourcode').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 58) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13 ) {
            $(this).val(
                $(this).val().substring(0, start)
                + "\t"
                + $(this).val().substring(end)
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: are you trying to get previous keycode?

Comment: Your second `if` statement will never be reached, cause if your current keycode is = 58, it will never be 13.

Comment: no.. but i want to trigger it when : is there in line and enter is pressed

Comment: What's `start` and `end`?

Comment: you can run code snippet

Comment: @RahulMohite, have you tested my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i told you in my comment, the second `if` statement will not be reached, since if keyCode is = 58, it will never be 13.

Also, use `keyup` instead.

Check the code below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      var text = $(this).val().trim();

      if (text.substring(text.length - 1) == ':') {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\t');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="yourcode" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control">
</textarea>
```

Comment: What's not working? It adds a tab when you type ":" and enter. Isn't this what you asked for?

Comment: on enter key it tab is not coming

Comment: What do you mean? You want to add a tab IF the user has pressed ":" + enter on the previous line. Is that it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#yourcode').keypress(function(e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13){
   val = $(this).val();
   if(val.substr(val.length - 1) == ":"){
        console.log(": after enter")
        // your code here
        $('textarea').val(val.replace(/:/g, ':\n') + "   ");
   }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="yourcode" cols="40" rows="10" class="form-control">
 </textarea>
```

Comment: work how to give indentation at next line after enter